# How to implement search functionality in multiple row List view based on single row using text watcher in android

Tags: android, listview, search

I implemented multiple row list view(4 rows in single item).i want to search only based on second row in my list view.i implemented search functionality using text watcher that is not working properly. please help me guys.Thanks in advance.

```
           inputsearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputsearch);
           lst = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
           lst.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
           lst.setCacheColorHint(Color.WHITE);


           SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylistData,R.layout.simple_list_item2, row, new int[] { R.id.tv1,
            R.id.tv2, R.id.tv3, R.id.tv4, R.id.tv5 });
             lst.setAdapter(adapter);

         inputsearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            // String array_sort[]=new String[headlines.length];

            adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int start,
                int before, int count) {

        }
    });
```